# Math Module and variable functions

Tags: python

I am writing a code with the purpose of **calculating** a **math** **function** (given as an **input**) and calculate it with **different** **values** of **x** (without defining the x).

*Example: input: y=log(2x)  and i have to calculate for x=3,5,8*

With the math module is quite easy to calculate the value of y given x but i can't find a solution to keep the x as variable and then calculate y depending on the change of x.
Since the moment that i can't write the function as a string i tried to define a new function

*Example: def function(f, x)*

So i just needed to input function(f=math.log(2x),x) but the problem is still there because when i recall the function changing the x (Example : function(f,x=5)) i don't have the f defined anymore.

So briefly, how i can make the functions of the math module dipendent from x?

Comment: I think what you're looking for (inlinable function definition I presume?) is called lambda functions. e.g. `function(lambda x: math.log(2*x), x)`

Comment: No the problem was that i don't need a specific function but i would like to insert it like as an imput or as an attribute of a function, having the possibility to choose without modify the code

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to define a new function.

```
def example(x):
    return math.log(2 * x)
```

Then you can call the function using the usual syntax

```
example(x)
```

As correctly noted in the comments, you can also define this function using anonymous syntax

```
example = lambda x: math.log(2 * x)
example(x)
```

Although this sort of defeats the purpose of anonymous functions if you're planning on giving the function a name anyway.

Comment: This works but doesn't solve the problem because i wanted to have the opportunity to input the function, in this way i can change it only modifying the code

Comment: If you want outside users to be able to input functions, you'll need to write a parser to understand it. You can also use `eval`, but you absolutely should not do that because it's vulnerable to a thousand security holes that neither of us is equipped to deal with correctly.